# Publish ASP.NET MVC 4 (Razor) app onto remote server running Windows 7 with IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have experience in hosting an Asp mvc 4 application on local IIS with Sql server as back end. Now I want to host this application on another system that don't have Sql server and Visual studio installed. I think we can able to get all files necessary to host by publish option in visual studio 2012. But I don't have any idea on how to make my database working on the server without sql server and the necessary connection strings. Can I change my db to sql server compact 4.0?

Please give the necessary instructions.

Comment: Install SQL Server Express, it's free.

Comment: ya. But is it secure to give full controll of the db to our client

Comment: I want to host my db without sql server

Answer (score 1):

For .net Application you can generate necessary files using publish feature of VS.You can even make use of web-deploy for direct deployment of artifacts to remote server itself.

For db you better have sql -engine, without that it get's tricky. Express edition will always be better option if you are not looking for some advanced DBA jobs.